# How to create a registry analyzer

Tags: registry, analyzer

I am trying to make a new type of anti malware program and one of the biggest hurdles that I can’t figure out is how to take all the registry values in the Computer to check for unwanted or harmful registries in c or c++ does anyone know how to do this or know where to look at solving this?

Comment: Also I would like a low level answer that could work for windows 95 or nt 5.0 because it will add extra security for the people who still use those operating systems too

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.